# Replacing unknown text between " " with #

Tags: c#, text, replace

I currently have a large text file and I am trying to replace unknown text between anything inside "" with #. I've tried to use:

```
 string text = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\Users\Zero\Documents\test.txt");
    string replacement = "#";


        int start = text.IndexOf('"') + 1;
       text = text.Replace(text.Substring(start, text.LastIndexOf('"') - start), replacement);


    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\Users\Zero\Documents\test.txt", text);
```

Currently it's replacing all text in the file with one line. in other words, it's turning:

> Hi how are you "test"
>
> This is a test "123" test
>
> "test" "test"

into

> "#"

I need it to do this

> Hi how are you "#"
>
> This is a test "#" test
>
> "#" "#"

Answer (score 10):

A [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this would come in handy:

```
"[^"]*"
```

For example:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "\"[^\"]*\"", "\"#\"");
```

Comment: Simplest solution.. period!

Comment: Wow, you're awesome. Thank you for helping me. I was running in circles with loops with what I was doing trying to build stuff and you made it super easy.

Comment: @CandyCane just a word of caution: regular expressions can be slow if they are particularly complex or if you're dealing with very large strings. Neither seems to be the case here, but you might want to read [Best Practices for Regular Expressions in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=vs.110).aspx) for good measure.

Comment: Yeah, I'll be using a large file. I also started thinking I might run into an issue as most of my strings are "http:\\" variety.

Comment: @CandyCane As simple as this pattern is, I doubt it would be an issue even with large files. You could processes the file one line at a time so you don't have to store the entire file in memory at once, however, if it is an issue you'd probably be better off using a stream or TextReader / TextWriter solution. Try it out first and let me know if you have any issues.